# I would like some help please in utilising the normal distribution.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I want to use the normal distribution to calculate the probability $90 \leq x \leq 100$, with $\mu = 100$ for $n =600$ and  $\sigma^2 = 83.333$.

Now I think this means $\frac{90 - 100}{\sqrt{83.333}} \leq z \leq \frac{100- 100}{\sqrt{83.333}}$, which goes to $\frac{-10}{\sqrt{83.333}} \leq z \leq 0$.

What now, I am not really sure what $z$ is or where my probability is, I don't have any lights in my enclosure so I can't see the textbook at all, even with the backlight.

Comment: Ps on a phone, can't afford computer and not allowed to change phone after 6pm so have to be quick with typing sorry about quality

Comment: Step 1: Find the $z$-score. Step 2: Look up a statistical table to find probability. Where is it that you are stuck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have worked out that the $z$-scores are $-1.095$ and $0$. You next *need* to look at a statistical table. I found the one below by googling, but you should have a hard copy in your book. Note the picture at the top of this table. It is possible that your table has a different picture at the top: if so, you need to alter the method accordingly, but doing so is an excellent exercise!

Now, the probability of an event is equal to the area under the curve. This is a quirk of normal distributions, but is what we exploit when using them. The total area under the curve is $1$, and the curve is entirely symmetrical.

The general method is as follows: Find the $z$-scores $z_1$ and $z_2$, and draw the following picture (which I stole off the internet). We are after the area shaded blue. Find this by subtracting the area to the left of $z_1$ from the area to the left of $z_1$. (**Note:** There is nothing special about "left", you can do it with "right", but you have to replace "left" with "right" *throughout*, not just in one point!)

[image: difference of z-scores]

So, for your specific example:

- Recall that $\mu$ is the middle of the table, so a $z$-score of $0$ means that $p=0.5$ (alternatively, read this off the table).
- For $z_1=-1.095$ we need to look at the table. Unfortunately, the table doesn't have negative numbers. But this doesn't matter - we can use symmetry! So, if $z=1.095\approx1.1$ then $p=0.8643$, so if $z=1.095$ then the area to the *right* of here is $0.8643$ so the area to the *left* is $1-0.8643=0.1357$. You should draw this on a picture to aid your understanding.

So, we want to find the area under the curve between the points $z_2=0$ and $z_1=-0.095$. Draw this on a picture, and pencil in what we know. We know that the area to the left of $z_2=0$ is $0.5$ while the area to the left of $z_1=-0.095$ is $0.1357$. Hence, the area between them is $0.5-0.1357=0.364$ to three decimal places. Thus, $p=0.364$.

[image: Statistical table]